# Detect loops in geometry

Tags: geometry

I tried asking this on Stack Overflow, but didn't get a response. In lieu of a Stack Geometry, I'm asking here hoping for a better response.

I'm looking for a way to detect loops in geometry using VBA (not excel). I start with a geometric shape, containing an outer profile. It may also contain inner profiles and open or closed loops.

*EDIT* - To clarify, the geometry is presented as a series of lines with endpoints. Programmatically, it's not known if the lines are joined or form a loop. The purpose of this question is to identify a way to identify the loops (open and closed)

So far, I can iterate through each line, and look for lines with a start or end point that matches my

The image below is a simplified example. The black lines are the geometry, and each line has start and end points (red crosses) with X & Y Coordinates.

[image: Example geometry set, with points and lines. Each line is labelled.]

Its easy enough to detect whether lines are joined (or not) to other lines (for example, I can identify that the vertical line at the top is not connected to the rest of the lines).

The aim is to identify 4 closed loops and 1 open loop in this image. The closed loops should be:

- The outer profile - 1, 2, 3.....8, 9, 10
- The top inner profile. - 1, 2, 3, 11, 9, 10
- The bottom inner profile. - 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11
- The circle - 12
- The open loop should be the vertical line at the top - 13

Note that the first 3 profiles share geometry - this is acceptable.

I found a possible solution some time back when looking for a solution to a 3D problem, whereby you take any point on the surface of the object and cast a ray in the two directions normal to the surface. If the ray passes through 0 (not including itself) or an even number of surfaces (including itself), then it's an outer profile. If it passes through an odd number of surfaces (including itself), then it's an internal profile. However, in this case, the inclusion of open internal loops messes that up.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT [01/22]: Added definitions below.**

**Definitions:**

- **Closed loop** - A series of one or more lines in which the start point IS the same as the end point. Closed loops should not cross (e.g. figure 8) this would be considered 2 separate  loops.
- **Open loop** - A series of one or more lines which do not form a closed loop - that is, the end point is NOT the same as the start point.
- **Outer Profile** - A closed loop within which, all other loops should exist. There should be exactly 1 outer loop for any given set of geometry.
- **Inner Profile** - A loop (open or closed) that is either partially or completely within the outer profile. An inner profile may use some of the same lines as the outer profile. For example the top and bottom inner profiles (refer to line sequences above) use some of the outer profile lines, but not all.

**EDIT [01/22]: Added labels to the image.**

Comment: If you are able to have an approximate at each point (numericaly speaking)  a value of the angle (in [0,360°] range made by the tangent at any point, you have a loop if the traversal of your curve yields a 360° total turn of your tangent.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez - Correct. We could change the terminology if you like, but it won't help solve the problem.

Comment: @JeanMarie - I don't understand - could you provide an example as an answer perhaps?

Comment: I had hoped that the example explained it sufficiently. I have added definitions to help aid your understanding.

Comment: If you think of your curve as the trajectory of a vehicle, and you take its "instantaneous" speed vector, this vector (do you know the concept of "hodograph") will undergo a $360°$ turn if and only if the curve is closed.

Comment: @JeanMarie - That's true for a square, but that angle changes depending on the shape of the object right?

Comment: Only focus your calculation on the difference between the initial and the final state of the "needle on the clock" (see in the litterature what I call a "hodograph") : has it, yes or no, undergone a 360° turn ?

Comment: @JeanMarie - Ok, I think I get it now. I think that test demonstrates that a given loop is closed (the current test is to see if the start point coordinates equal the end point coordinates). But I don't see how it helps to identify the loops (i.e. which series of lines form a loop). The question refers to identifying the loops, not testing if they're closed.
I'll re-phrase the question to clarify.

Comment: What's an "inner profile"? "outer profile"?  Do the red X's have any meaning?  Is the input to your VBA program an image?  Or a graph ?(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)).

Comment: I've added definitions of 'inner profile' and 'outer profile', as well as a more thorough explanation of the loop examples with line sequence numbers.

Comment: By matching up the endpoints of your curves, you can reduce your data to a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), and then your problem reduces to [cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Cycle_detection).

Comment: Thanks - that looks very much similar to my problem. I'll investigate further.